# MacBook Pro mini displayport to DVI D doesn't show anything on the Compaq 2021 monitor

Tags: display, displayport, dvi

I am using a MacBook Pro running 10.6.8. I have been using a Compaq s2021a monitor with mini displayport to VGA adaptor and cable until now. I bought a mini displayport to DVI adaptor and DVI - DVI cable and connected to the monitor. The laptop is detecting the display and allows me to change the resolution but nothing is seen on the display of the monitor. There is a flicker on the screen when the resolution is changed to 1024x768 when I click on the calibrate button.

Can someone help me to resolve this?

Comment: What DVI cable did you get? Both the monitor and the Mini Displyport to DVI adapter are DVI-D and you will require the correct type of DVI cable

Comment: Are you saying the monitor was working with a mini display port to VGA set up and it has recently stopped working? And then you bought a mini-display port to DVI adapter and that too does not work?

Comment: @Stu Wilson I was on vacation and got busy with other professional activities and didn't return back to this page. THe mini displayport DVI adaptor with the DVI-D cable works perfect with other monitors and sony projector but does not work with my COmpaq 2021 monitor which has a DVI-D input.

Comment: Does the on screen display show AUTO, VGA, or DVI when a signal cable is connected? What happens when you press and hold the OK/Auto button for 5 seconds?

Comment: The screen is totally black. Pressing the control butons in the monitor doesn't show up anything. Changing resolutions through the laptop shows some flicker in 1024x768. otherwise it is totally black.

Answer (score 1):

If you were using vga before, the monitor may not take digital input. DVI-D is digital only. VGA is analogue.

Try using a DVI-A or similar analogue signal.

Comment: The [product-page for the monitor](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02207211&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&product=4121885) states `Input terminal 1 DVI-D connector 
1 VGA connector`, so it's not a VGA only display.